# Remove b'' (encoded result) on text in dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks like the following.

| id | body |
| --- | --- |
| 12 | b'I added an AttributeInput.js file, which can be used as a reusable component for attribute panels generated for the templates.' |
| 73 | b'Adding template functionality: SVG dimensions now work' |

I want to remove b" from every line of text in that column. The b" exists because of the encoding. I've tried using the following method.

```
df['body'] = df['body'].str.decode('utf-8')
```

But that method doesn't work. Instead it deletes every text in the column so that it produces nan values in each row of the text column. Can anyone help me?

Comment: You should change the method with which you populate the dataframe in the first place not to put the repr of a bytes object in there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might be able to do

```
import ast

df['body'] = df['body'].map(lambda v: ast.literal_eval(v).decode())
```

which will evaluate the b'' repr string to a real bytes object, then decode it so you get a string.

Comment: hello, thanks for your answer. but i have error after implementing it.
the error is as follows
`EOL while scanning string literals`

Comment: Then some of your data can't be interpreted as a Python literal,most likely if it's an empty string. You could try a default: `ast.literal_eval(v or 'b""').decode()`

Comment: I've fixed the dataframe, and it's works. Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

here the solution

```
import pandas as pd

data = {'id': [12, 73, 100], 
        'body':[b"""I added an AttributeInput.js file, which can be used as a 
                reusable component for attribute panels generated for the 
                templates.""", 
                b"""Adding template functionality: SVG dimensions now work""", 
               """test string"""]}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)
df
    id                                               body
0   12  b'I added an AttributeInput.js file, which can...
1   73  b'Adding template functionality: SVG dimension...
2  100                                        test string
```

converting

```
df['body'].apply(lambda x:x.decode('utf8') if isinstance(x, bytes) else x)
```

output

```
0    I added an AttributeInput.js file, which can b...
1    Adding template functionality: SVG dimensions ...
2                                          test string
Name: body, dtype: object
```

so if you want to override the column `body`:

```
df['body'] = df['body'].apply(lambda x:x.decode('utf8', "ignore") if isinstance(x, bytes) else x)
df
    id                                               body
0   12  I added an AttributeInput.js file, which can b...
1   73  Adding template functionality: SVG dimensions ...
2  100                                        test string
```

before change:

```
df['body'].apply(lambda x: type(x))
0    <class 'bytes'>
1    <class 'bytes'>
2      <class 'str'>
Name: body, dtype: object
```

after change

```
df['body'] = df['body'].apply(lambda x:x.decode('utf8', "ignore") if isinstance(x, bytes) else x)
df['body'].apply(lambda x: type(x))
0    <class 'str'>
1    <class 'str'>
2    <class 'str'>
Name: body, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but this method doesn't change anything. The text remains in the form of encoding.

Comment: did you try because it's work, see again the example

Comment: This doesn't work for OP because they have a dataframe with string representations of bytestrings, not a dataframe with arbitrary objects (byteses)